# How can I paste a text into multiple textboxes at once, instead of individually one by one, in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a slide with many rectangles, and I'd like to paste a certain text in each of them, without individually pasting it in each one. If possible, formatted text.

I'd like to be able to select all of the rectangles and then simply click paste, but what happens is that instead it creates a new text box and pastes the text there.

Is there a way to insert the same text in multiple text boxes at once? The rectangles are already preplaced in exact positions, so I can't just start with a new text box and then copy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is posible to do if there is already text in those textboxes or shapes. You have to select the text inside each shape and paste the text you want there.

In detail:

1. Make sure you the shapes already have text inside them (a single letter is OK).
2. Copy the text (ctrl-c or cmd-c) you want to paste into the shapes.
3. Select the text inside each shape. You can do this by first selecting the text in one shape, and then using ctrl to select the text in the other shapes.
4. Paste the text normally (ctrl-v or cmd-v) and it will replace the text you selected in all the shapes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That actually works. Didn't know you could select different texts in different textboxes at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe useless, but copy&paste your text into a rectangle. At first copy the text, not any text frame, but the text content to the clipboard.

Select a rectangle and press Ctrl+V to paste what's in the clipboard. It's not the same as creating a new text frame. The rectangle becomes your text frame.

You can do the same to all rectangles.

If the text happens already be in one rectangle you can select the text content in that rectangle (not the rectangle itself). Then drag the selected text to all rectangles one by one by holding the Ctrl key at the same time. Ctrl+drag creates a copy.